# cfmap in II7 not loading

Tags: iis, coldfusion

Below is the sample code that works locally, but not on the server.
The local dev environment is not in IIS, but in Coldfusion 9.

```
<cfmap name="name" 
centerlatitude="36.82617" 
centerlongitude="-1.27431" 
doubleclickzoom="true" 
overview="true" 
scrollwheelzoom="true" 
showscale="true" 
tip="My Map" 
zoomlevel="13"
typecontrol="basic"
height="600"
width ="600"/>
```

The google map key is intered via cfajaximport.

Thank you.

Comment: You'll need to provide a description of exactly what's happening, as well as the rendered source code in the browser. The first thing I would suggest you check though, is whether the CFIDE directory is properly set up on your production server.

Comment: The screen does not show any errors, its just blank. If I use the iframes from google directly, the iframe map works. It also looks like the other javascript tags do not work. What could cause coldfusion not render javascript through it's tags in IIS7?

Comment: +1 for making sure CFIDE is set up as a virtual directory in the web server

Comment: Yep, the problem was with the cfide configuration. IIS, there was ip restrictions on the dir.

Comment: If you don't mind marking my posted answer as the solution, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this as the answer, since I had it as part of the comment.

In order to make sure that any CF ajax functionality works correctly, you have to make sure that the CFIDE directory is properly configured under the site. It needs to be at the root of the site, and publicly accessible.

Dan